# nginx certbot certificate www and non-www

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

I haven't really wrapped my head around how to create (working) certificates using certbot for nginx.

My sites-enables now look like this:

First, a block for the www domain with SSL. All the SSL stuff is created by certbot.

```
server {
root …
index … 
server_name www.doman.com
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate …
ssl_certificate_key …
include …
ssl_dhparam … 
}
```

After this, a redirect from port 80 to port 443 for both www and non-www. The first part – the if statement – is created by certbot and not me.

```
server {
if ($host = www.example.com {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

listen *:80;
server_name domain.com www.example.com;
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

}

And finally, a block for 443 without www. I want this to redirect to www.

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name www.domain.com
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This plays out well for the domain with www. However, without www, I get "this site cannot be reached". Even when I try it with http and and not https.

Where am I fucking this up? My guess is that the third block, that used 443 for non-www, needs SSL certificates as well. But I use certbots automatic creation, and it doesn't add any.

Answer (score 12):

I don't allow certbot to create my web server configurations. I frankly don't trust it to get it right, since it's already doing some not very efficient practices.

So I get certs with `certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www -d hostname -d hostname` ...

And my nginx configuration looks like this (for one example domain):

```
server {
    server_name www.yes-www.org yes-www.org;

    access_log off;

    include includes/listen-80;
    include includes/cloudflare;
    include includes/letsencrypt;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

For port 80 I'm just serving both hostnames and redirecting to https and www unconditionally.

```
server {
    server_name yes-www.org;

    access_log off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yes-www.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yes-www.org/privkey.pem;

    include includes/listen-443;
    include includes/cloudflare;
    include includes/ssl;
    include includes/hsts;
    include includes/letsencrypt;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.yes-www.org$request_uri;
    }
}
```

For port 443 non-www I'm just redirecting to www unconditionally.

```
server {
    server_name www.yes-www.org;

    root /srv/www/yes-www.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/yes-www.org-access.log nginx;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/cache.log cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/yes-www.org-error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yes-www.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yes-www.org/privkey.pem;

    include includes/listen-443;
    include includes/cloudflare;
    include includes/letsencrypt;
    include includes/ssl;
    include includes/hsts;
    include includes/favicon;
    include includes/wordpress;
    include includes/php;
    include /srv/www/yes-www.org/nginx.conf;

    location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And finally here I'm serving a web site.

Note that the contents of `/etc/nginx/includes/letsencrypt` are:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Which makes `certbot certonly` as above work.

Comment: +1 for the shared webroot for every `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`. If I had only thought of that before, I would have saved a lot of configuration lines and time (using `certonly`, but configured every vhost separately). This is simply elegant and easy to maintain.

Comment: This is incredibly well structured, and very educational. Wish I'd seen it sooner! Do you maybe have all those conf files up somewhere like github or a gist? Would be very helpful to see how they're written, especially the `listen-80.conf` and `listen-443.conf`.

Comment: @lonix I'll be publishing something in the next few months. Stay tuned!

Comment: Looking forward to it! This structure is crazy smart, I want to dig deeper. The best nginx content here is usually from you :-)