# How to make Certbot ignore a particular domain in nginx?

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have ~30 domains running on my server, all of them with SSL certificates managed by the Certbot nginx plugin. All of them, except one... let's call it `selfsigned.example.com`.

This domain uses a self-signed certificate because it's being accessed by an embedded device, for which I haven't managed to get a proper certificate chain to work. The embedded device checks the certificate fingerprint, so it's quite secure as long as I don't need revocation. But it's important that the cert on the server doesn't get replaced by Certbot, otherwise the device will refuse to connect.

I frequently add new domains to the configuration, and then I rerun `certbot --nginx` to generate a new certificate for them. But every time I do that, `certbot` prompts me:

```
Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: whatever.example.com
2: something.example.com
...
17: selfsigned.example.com
...
32: thelastone.example.com
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel):
```

If I just press Enter, Certbot will overwrite the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives for `selfsigned.example.com` with a cert from Let's Encrypt. So I have to manually type out all numbers except 17 in this case.

As a cautious and lazy sysadmin, how can I make it so that I can just press Enter? Maybe there's some magic comment (similar to `# managed by Certbot`) that lets me say `# Certbot ignore`?

Comment: I neither use nor recommend the certbot nginx plugin. The configuration it writes isn't very good. And of course it doesn't seem to work very well for your use case. See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/896555/126632) for my sample configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The thought hadn't even occurred to me. Does your certbot still _parse_ the list of domains from your nginx config, or do you have to maintain that list in two places?

Comment: No, I specify the domains on the command line. This is only an issue when initially getting certificates; of course it remembers them for renewals. And of course you can automate the initial bit too, in your configuration management or even a shell script.

Comment: without changing to a different certificate manager, and assuming certbot does not have the capability you want, why not store a csv containing all servers except #17 and copy paste.

Comment: @TimmyBrowne Because the numbers may change as I add/remove domains. I think certbot orders them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed certbot's nginx configuration management is... not great. It makes a mess of your config whenever it decides to rewrite parts of it.

But: Let's Encrypt supports wildcard certificates. So I just created a wildcard cert for `example.com,*.example.com` and manually configured it in nginx.