# Change Certbot plugin

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a web server running multiple sites on nginx. They are secured by certificates from Lets Encrypt. For some reason, long ago, I installed the certs for one site using `standalone` rather than the `nginx` plugin.

So when `certbot renew` runs, it always fails when that domain is due for renewal because nginx is running on port 80. I have to stop nginx, and re-run certbot, and then restart nginx.

When I run `certbot renew --nginx` it complains that HTTP validation fails for those domains. I'm having difficulty figuring out how I can tell certbot to revalidate the domains by HTTP and switch them to the nginx plugin.

Comment: I would not do that at all. See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/896555/126632).

Comment: My main concern is not having to stop nginx so standalone can bind to :80. So I’m open to ideas.

Comment: Then click the link.

Comment: I would remove the existing certificate and install a new one.