# Can I enable TLS 1.3 with Certbot?

Tags: nginx, ssl, certbot

I am working with Nginx and Certbot, I have secured a domain with HTTPS. I would like to get the domain up to TLS 1.3.

The Nginx server block for my domain get's it's SSL protocols from the included file Certbot creates.

The file `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf` states that if I modify the file Certbot will be unable to automatically provide security updates.

I want to modify the file's `ssl_protocols` line by adding `TLSv1.3` to the end, but I do not want to break certbot's automatic updates.

Is is possible to tell certbot to enable TLS 1.3?

Software Versions

- Nginx 1.14.0
- OpenSSL 1.1.1
- Certbot 0.31.0
- Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I don't use or recommend certbot's nginx plugin. I prefer to do it standalone and write the nginx config (correctly) myself. [Here is a working sample configuration.](https://serverfault.com/a/896555/126632)

Comment: Well I added TLSv1.3 to the ssl_protocols line in that file anyway. Ssllabs.com states that TLS 1.3 is enabled. I'm just concerned that i will miss important security updates from certbot.

Comment: @Michael Hampton  are you saying you get the cert with `certbot certonly --webroot` comand, and write the configuration yourself with the example content? Assuming i used `certbot --nginx` command i should be able to rewrite my configuration to match your example right?

Comment: Yes, you could rewrite the configuration. You'd also want to rewrite the configuration in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/whatever.conf`.

Comment: Go to https://www.nginxconfig.io Buy someone a coffee for this amazing tip.

Answer (score 0):

If you install an updated version of Certbot you will have TLS 1.3 enabled by default, Snap is the best way to install Certbot (More instructions here: https://certbot.eff.org/).

```
#This instructions works for Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04
#first we need to be sure there is not another certbot installed    
sudo apt-get remove certbot -y < /dev/null
#install Certbot by Snap packaging
sudo snap install --classic certbot
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

Later run Certbot like you want

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d yourdomain.com --agree-tos -m youremail@example.com --redirect
```

Or

```
sudo certbot certonly --nginx -d yourdomain.com --agree-tos -m youremail@example.com --redirect
```

Or

```
sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/yourdomain.com/public_html -d yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx/ Ubuntu doesn't support TLSv1.3 on SSL Libary level. So you would need to rebuild the whole ssl stack and compile everything from source
Ubuntu 18.04 ships with OpenSSL 1.1.0. Replacing the system OpenSSL library isn’t a good idea, but you can download OpenSSL 1.1.1 source code and compile Nginx with OpenSSL 1.1.1 source code to enable TLS 1.3.

https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/6367#issuecomment-601937964
Certbot supports tls1.3 when nginx and openssl support it with the most recent version

Comment: 18.04 [is end of life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). It should not be used for production.

Comment: The Q already (3 years ago) specifies OpenSSL 1.1.1. @vidarlo: the Q was asked in 2020, when 18.04 was fully alive.